# Modify the value overriding a property willSet get/set

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom `UILabel` and I override it's text property. I need to modify the value of this property if `upperCase = true` and the problem is that I’m calling recursively the setter.

```
@IBDesignable class CustomLabel: UILabel {
@IBInspectable var upperCase: Bool = false
override var text: String? {
    willSet {
        if upperCase == true {
            text = newValue?.uppercaseString  
        }
    }
}
}
```

I also tried:

```
var aux: String?
override var text: String? {
    get { return aux }
    set {  aux = newValue }
}
```

But the text label is not set. Any suggestion?

Comment: before set: text = newValue?.uppercaseString  you can check if newValue is already in uppercase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use super

```
override var text: String? {
    get { return super.text }
    set(v){  super.text = v }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer shows you how to modify the text as it's being set, but it doesn't specifically address the question, which asked how to create a `UILabel` subclass that will automatically make the text uppercase.

Here's a `UILabel` subclass that will always be uppercase

```
import UIKit

class UppercaseLabel: UILabel{

    override var text: String?{
        get{
            return super.text
        }
        set(newText){
            super.text = newText?.uppercaseString
        }
    }
}
```